# Trying to find an equation for distance you can go based on Xpos and Ypos of a robot, robot angle, and distance from an object.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, robotics

So I have a robot, and I am trying to push an object into a red border without falling off the edge. the border is 100mm thick, the whitespace in between the 4 borders in the square is 2000x2000mm, and the total dimensions of the board are 2200x2200. I am trying to find an equation I can use for the distance I can go to push the block into the red border without falling off the edge, using the robot's X position, Y position, angle, and the distance from the object.
[image: Sorry for bad handwriting lol]

Comment: Please attach a picture. The setup is not clear.

Comment: I have added it!

Comment: Still not clear how the whole system moves. What's the original position of the object? Is the only thing that you know is that is that a given angle from Xpos and Ypos? Do you keep pushing in the same direction (same angle) until the object reaches the border?

Comment: The angle, Xpos Ypos, angle and distance from object are variable. And, yes, you keep pushing in the same direction. Basically how the robot works is it will rotate until it senses something in it's path, and if it senses it, it can calculate the distance from that object as a variable using lasers.

Comment: I don't see how distance from the object is pertinent. When the robot is pushing the object, that distance is $0$ (at least, at the pushing surface). All the robot needs to know is its own distance from the border in the direction of the object, and that is just simple trigonometry.

Comment: In your picture, you write angle, and draw a line from it to the vector pointing in the direction of the object. Angles and vectors are two different things. If you have that vector - you actually don't need the angle. What you would do if you actually had an angle is take the cosine and sine of it. And the cosine and sine are just the components of the unit vector in that same direction. So which is it? Do you have that vector, or do you have an angle, and if you do have an angle, what is the other side of that angle?

Comment: So it measures the distance from the object only once, which is for the distance it is from the object at the time of measurement, which is variable depending on the coords of the robot. Also, it would probably be vector. An easier thing to solve this problem would also be to determine the coordinates of the object, as I can use it to simplify the original problem.

Comment: @j4kj4k08 Let us assume that the robot sits at some known position and faces upwards. Then, it rotates a known angle from the upward direction until its laser-eye sees the object in question. Now, you have to tell us how the robot pushes the object, whether it is using its extractable arm (if it has an arm) or it travels to the object and gives a series of nudges in the direction it travelled to reach the object.

Comment: @YNK It would give the object a series of nudges in order to push the object.

Answer (score 1):

[image: RobotPushingObject]

Your question is not a difficult proposition by any means. If you have drawn a decent diagram of the scenario described in your problem statement, probably you could have solved it yourself. It requires only fundamental knowledge of trigonometry and algebra, and Pythagoras’ theorem. Please note that all the lengths are given in $\pmb{meters}$.

As shown in our two sketches, $T_0$ and $T_1$ are the starting and the final position of the object pushed by the robot respectively. It is given that the point $T_0$ is located a distance of $a$ from the upper-right corner $E$ of the inner square. The starting position of the robot is $R_0$, while the origin $O$ of the coordinate system is at the bottom-left corner of the inner square. The values of $\space{\large{x}}_{R_0},\space {\large{y}}_{R_0},\space a,\space$ and $\space \theta\space$ are known and you are seeking an expression for $T_0T_1 \left(=b\right)$ in terms those four values.

There are two different scenarios depending on the values of $\theta$ and $\varphi$, where the latter is the angle between $T_0E$ and the $y\text{-axis}$. First of all, you need to determine $d$, the distance between the robot and the object at the start as shown below.

$$T_0C = OG – OA – R_0B=2-{\large{x}}_{R_0}-d\sin\left(\theta\right)\quad$$
$$EC=AF-AR_0-BT_0=2-{\large{y}}_{R_0}- d\cos\left(\theta\right)$$

Now, we apply Pythagoras’ theorem to the right-angled triangle $T_0CE$ to obtain,
$$a^2=\left(2-{\large{x}}_{R_0}-d\sin\left(\theta\right)\right)^2+\left(2-{\large{y}}_{R_0}- d\cos\left(\theta\right)\right)^2.$$

After simplifying this, we rearrange its like terms together to produce the following quadratic equation in $d$.
$$d^2{\small{-}}2\Big(\big(2{\small{-}}{\large{x}}_{R_0}\big)\sin\left(\theta\right){\small{+}} \big(2{\small{-}}{\large{y}}_{R_0}\big)\cos\left(\theta\right)\Big)d {\small{+}} 8{\small{-}}a^2{\small{+}} {\large{x}}_{R_0}^2 {\small{+}} {\large{y}}_{R_0}^2 {\small{-}} {\large{x}}_{R_0}{\small{-}} {\large{y}}_{R_0}=0 \tag{1}$$

Equation (1) has two positive real roots. It can be shown that the smaller of the two roots is the value of $d$. When we have $d$, we can find $\phi$ using properties of  the right-angle triangle $T_0CE$.
$$\varphi = \sin^{-1}\left(\dfrac{2-{\large{x}}_{R_0}-d\sin\left(\theta\right)}{a}\right). \tag{2}$$

Once we know the value of $\varphi$, we can use it to differentiate between the two scenarios.

In the first of the two possible scenarios (see $\mathrm{Fig.\space 1}$), we have $\phi \ge \theta$. For this case, following equation expressing the sought distance $b$ can be derived. using properties of the right-angle triangle $T_0DT_1$.
$$b=\left(\dfrac{2.1-{\large{y}}_{R_0}}{\cos\left(\theta\right)}\right)-d\tag{3.1}$$

$\mathrm{Fig.\space 2}$ depicts the second scenario, which is characterized by the fact $\phi \le \theta$.  In this instance, the equation for determining $b$ takes the form,
$$b=\left(\dfrac{2.1-{\large{x}}_{R_0}}{\sin\left(\theta\right)}\right)-d.\tag{3.2}$$

Comment: Thanks! That helped a ton!